# How to fix WordPress 404 links issues behind reverse proxy

Tags: wordpress, nginx, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy

My main website is  www.example.com (host1, nginx)
my blog is blog.example.com (host2 , aws lightsail bitnami) .

For SEO we would like to https://www.example.com/blog to reverse proxy https://blog.example.com

I've configured reverse proxy on  host1 nginx   and configured wp-config on host2.
when i go to /blog it works but the internal post links leads to 404

Example of internal link - https://www.example.com/2019/01/02/post-year-in-review/

It looks like its going to the main domain (host1 example.com) and looking for the post there.

Please see configuration below.

```
under nginx /etc/nginx/conf.d/example-ssl.conf  (HOST 1 NGINX)   
location ^~ /blog {
    proxy_pass http://HOST2_IP_ADDRESS_HERE/blog;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_redirect http://HOST2_IP_ADDRESS_HERE/ https://$host/;
    proxy_cookie_domain HOST2_IP_ADDRESS_HERE $host;

}


wp-config.php (HOST 2 bitnami wordpress)

define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.example.com/blog');
define('WP_HOME', 'https://www.example.com/blog');
```

Comment: Are those internal links embedded into posts? If your site has moved form `/xxx` to `/blog/xxx`, you either need to edit every article with manually embedded links - or set up a rule to redirect `/2019/xxx` to `/blog/2019/xxx` and anything else your website uses.

Comment: @RichardSmith I'm not sure if they are,    i can see that the links to the posts are now https://www.example.com/blog/2019/01/02/example-year-in-review/ . which should go to . host1 nginx should do the proxy pass while keeping host    but what actually happens is that im getting 404 from host1 website..  how can i make the currect rewrite to fix those posts?

Comment: You are using `/blog` on `www.example.com`, but are you using `/blog` on host2? Do you expect `https://blog.example.com` to continue to work, or are you permanently migrating away from that site?

Comment: So what i need is . - blog.example.com . old links  will redirect 301 to www.example.com/blog (to avoid infinite loop ,  i check if host referer is not www.example.com and only then i redirect) . ..     and what i actually need is that www.example.com/blog will  reverse proxy to blog.example.com  and all the links inside blog.example.com will also work with the www.example.com/blog/bla/bla

Comment: Do you have any logs from host2?

Comment: Nothing in error logs just 404  in access , here is an example .  [20/Jan/2019:17:18:44 +0000] "GET /blog/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?v
er=4.9.9 HTTP/1.0" 404 50976

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187008/discussion-between-richard-smith-and-jamz).